# guzzle client throws exception in laravel

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am trying to make a http post request in laravel as below

```
$client = new Client(['debug'=>true,'exceptions'=>false]);
  $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://www.myservice.com/find_provider.php',  [
            'form_params' => [
                'street'=> 'test',
                'apt'=> '',
                'zip'=> 'test',
                'phone'=> 'test',
            ]
        ]);
```

It return empty response. On debugging ,following exception is occurring

curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE*

I am using latest version of guzzle.

Any idea how to solve it?.

Comment: Are you making a POST request to a service you have access to? Can you debug what is received there and if it's returning any data?

Comment: Yes it's a post request when I do $res->getBody() it return some data which doesn't show any expected output . I am trying.

Comment: Without viewing your full error output, it would seem that you are witnessing the same issues as referenced within this Guzzle bug post https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1413

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **request()** method is returning a **GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response** object.
To get the actual data that is returned by your service you should use:

```
$data = $res->getBody()->getContents();
```

Now check what you have in $data and if it corresponds to the expected output.

[More information on using Guzzle Reponse object here](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/response.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this

```
$data = $res->getBody()->getContents();<br>
but also change<br>
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false, 'debug' => true]);<br>
to<br> 
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did for my SMS api

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http; // Use this on top

// Sample Code
$response = Http::asForm()
           ->withToken(env('SMS_AUTH_TOKEN'))
           ->withOptions([
                         'debug'  => fopen('php://stderr', 'w') // Update This Line
            ])
            ->withHeaders([
                         'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
                         'Content-Type'  => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             ])
             ->post($apiUrl,$request->except('_token'));
```